# PyQt creating label that follows mouse

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt5

What I want to archive is a label that is created as soon as a button is pressed and follows the mouse until there is a 'click'.

My problem with that is that I can't seem to get the 'setMouseTracking(True)' command at the right widget...

```
    import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(0,0,1000,1100)
        self.main = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        canvas = QtGui.QPixmap(900, 900)
        canvas.fill(QtGui.QColor('#ffffff')) # Fill entire canvas.
        self.label.setPixmap(canvas)

        # self.last_x, self.last_y = None, None

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('create Block')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.buttonAction)

        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.label)
        vbox.addWidget(self.button)

        self.main.setLayout(vbox)
        # self.label.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setWindowTitle('testing')


    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        # if self.last_x is None: # First event.
            # self.last_x = e.x()
            # self.last_y = e.y()
            # return # Ignore the first time.

        # painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.label.pixmap())
        # painter.drawLine(self.last_x, self.last_y, e.x(), e.y())
        # painter.end()

        try:
            self.image.move(e.x(), e.y())
        except:
            pass
        self.update()

        # Update the origin for next time.
        # self.last_x = e.x()
        # self.last_y = e.y()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        # self.last_x = None
        # self.last_y = None

    def buttonAction(self):
        block = QtGui.QPixmap(20, 20)
        block.fill(QtGui.QColor('blue'))
        self.image = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.label)
        self.image.setPixmap(block)
        self.image.move(20,20)
        self.image.show()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

I don't know if my problem is that I attach setMouseTracking(True) to the wrong widget or if it is something else entirerly.
With clicking action it works, but that is not what I intend to do...

Edit: fixed some of the code issues

For clarification what my problem is: I have a canvas and a button inside an layout, as soon as the button is clicked a new canvas shall be created that follows the mouse pointer 'until' I click. So I don't want any kind of drag-and-drop action, but instead a small canvas that is following the mouse pointer.

This is needed as I intend to use the little canvas to show what an graphic would look like at a certain canvas position without printing it there. So the little canvas is something like a template.

Comment: Sorry for being so blunt, but your problem is not about the mouse tracking, as your code has *a lot* of issues, and frankly I don't even know where to start. Also, it's not very clear what you want to do: you want to create a label when the mouse is pressed *where*? And what if the button is pressed on the button? Please, clarify what you want to achieve, and, most importantly, check your code.

Comment: when the 'create Block' button is pressed, thats why I don't want the tracking to be a click action but simply a tracking until I click.

Comment: Sorry, it's still confusing. A label is created when clicking on the button, then *what* is following the mouse? Because in your code you're both trying to draw on a pixmap *and* moving another, and it's really unclear what you actually want to achieve. Do you want to "paint" lines after clicking a button and continue drawing until the mouse is released? Do you realize that this means that the painted line will always (theoreticallg) start from the button? Also, the `clicked` signals is actually emitted when the mouse button is released, not when it's pressed.

Comment: sorry, that is my bad. I just tried to quickly build a minimal example and used for that purpose a mini program that draws lines for mouse movements. I can comment that out, in my main application some other stuff is going on on the canvas.      I want the label that contains the new mini-canvas to follow the mouse until I click somewhere on the canvas. So my main problem is that I want this label to follow the mouse from the moment the button was clicked until I click with the mouse. But as of now it only follows the mouse, while the mouse-button is held down.

Comment: When creating examples you must ensure that they are not only minimal, but also *reproducible* (your code has a typo, as a B is missing in QPushButton) and readable. Never rush things, it's better to spend 10-15 more minutes on a well tailored code, than loose hours because others are not able to understand it. I suggest you to revise your code and edit the question with it while clarifying *there* what you need integrating what you wrote in the comments. Remember to always try to be as clear (while concise) as possible.

Comment: I can't find this typo you pointed out. I already did correct the question and the code. But thank you all the same for your tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some conceptual problems in your logic.

First of all, the mouse tracking only works for the widget it's set on. Also, if the widget accepts the mouse move event, the parent will not receive it.

In your case you are not receiving it because you are implementing the `mouseMoveEvent` in the main window, which by default ignores it if no mouse button is pressed (like most widgets).

While you could try to set it on the "target" widget *and* the parent (in your case, the canvas and the main window), you'll certainly have some issues at a certain point if any underlying widget accepts mouse movements; since you're going to need the "preview" only on the actual "canvas", there's no need to create a new widget, as you can just directly paint on the canvas instead, and finally draw on the actual pixmap only when needed.

This is a possible implementation:

```
class Canvas(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(900, 900)
        pixmap.fill(QtCore.Qt.white)
        self.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.preview = False

    def startPreview(self):
        self.preview = True
        self.update()

    def drawMiniCanvas(self, pos):
        pm = self.pixmap()
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(pm)
        qp.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.blue)
        if self.size() != pm.size():
            # if the pixmap is smaller than the actual size of the canvas, the position
            # must be translated to its contents before painting
            alignment = self.alignment()
            pmRect = pm.rect()
            if alignment == QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter:
                pmRect.moveCenter(self.rect().center())
            else:
                if alignment & QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter:
                    pmRect.moveLeft((self.width() - pm.width()) / 2)
                elif alignment & QtCore.Qt.AlignRight:
                    pmRect.moveRight(self.width())
                if alignment & QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter:
                    pmRect.moveTop((self.height() - pm.height()) / 2)
                elif alignment & QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom:
                    pmRect.moveBottom(self.height())
            pos -= pmRect.topLeft()
        qp.drawRect(pos.x(), pos.y(), 20, 20)
        qp.end()
        self.setPixmap(pm)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.preview:
            self.update()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self.preview:
            if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                self.drawMiniCanvas(event.pos())
            self.preview = False

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
        if self.preview:
            qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
            qp.drawRect(self.rect().adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1))
            pos = self.mapFromGlobal(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
            qp.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.blue)
            qp.drawRect(pos.x(), pos.y(), 20, 20)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(0,0,1000,1100)
        self.main = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main)

        self.canvas = Canvas()

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('create Block')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.canvas.startPreview)

        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.canvas)
        vbox.addWidget(self.button)

        self.main.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setWindowTitle('testing')
```

Note that I have left the main widget as a QLabel as per your code, but I strongly suggest to avoid so: QLabel has a complex management of its size, and even if you add a layout to it, the layout requirements will always be ignored; you should use a QWidget instead.

Finally, while the above code works, it's just a simple example based on your question; if you want to create a drawing tool, you should not use a QLabel, and for various reasons: for example, if you want to support scaling to fit the contents, not only the coordinate computation in `drawMiniCanvas` won't work (due to the scaling), but it will also not paint anything at all, and that's due to the way QLabel caches its contents whenever [`setScaledContents(True)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#scaledContents-prop) is used (also, it won't respect the aspect ratio).

For advanced and interactive painting, it's usually better to use a QGraphicsScene shown inside a QGraphicsView.